# how can i stop the orientation change in iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, screen-orientation

i am working with ipad. in my project, it need to see in portrait, not landscape. Now if i turn my ipad, my project as well changing to landscape mode.

But what i need is, if anyone turn they ipad also, my page view should not turn into landscape. than mean always my web page should be in portrait mode. for this how can i stop the orientation change?

and make my web view always in portrait?

any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` like this:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIDeviceOriention)orientation{
  if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
     return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, may be this is what i want. but how can i implement this?

Comment: Add this code to the view controller that you doubt want to rotate.